# How to highlight the found text in javascript

Tags: javascript, replace

I am trying to implement find and replace text in an html document using javascript.The replacement part works ok. But i would like to highlight the text that are going to be replaced in the html document (like in chrome when we use ctrl + f).So far my code is

```
<form name ="rep" class="replace" id="repf">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Replace <input class="data1" type="text" id="rp" onchange="highlight()"></td>
            <td>With    <input type="text" id="ne"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="button" onclick="replace();" value="confirm"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

so i have used an onchange event to the input field and callded the function highlight()

```
function replace() {
    var tx = document.getElementById('rp').value;
    var ne = document.getElementById('ne').value;
    var re = new RegExp(tx, "g");
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(re, ne);
    document.getElementById('repf').style.display = 'none';
}

function highlight() {
    var tx = 0;
    tx = document.getElementById('rp').value;
    alert(tx);
    var ne = '<span style="color:blue;">' + tx + '</span>';
    var de = new RegExp(tx, "g");
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(de, ne);
    return;
}
```

But after the onchange event the the value of the input field gets cleared.pls help

Comment: something like this for highlighting? http://jsfiddle.net/crustyashish/rGrvf/1/

Comment: can we impelement it without using jquery...i am tryng to learn javascript

Answer (score 2):

[edit](http://jsfiddle.net/crustyashish/5xZKe/2/)

[search](http://jsfiddle.net/crustyashish/5xZKe/1/)

**Script**

```
function highlight() {
    var text = document.getElementById("text-search").value;
    var query = new RegExp("(\\b" + text + "\\b)", "gim");
    var e = document.getElementById("mydata").innerHTML;
    var enew = e.replace(/(<span>|<\/span>)/igm, "");
    document.getElementById("mydata").innerHTML = enew;
    var newe = enew.replace(query, "<span>$1</span>");
    document.getElementById("mydata").innerHTML = newe;
}
```